# .Net Framework 4.6.1 requires

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-server-2008-r2, .net-framework-version

I wrote my program with .net framework 4.5 (all class libraries (DLL) and .exe) I created a setup but when I'm trying to install this program it says:
- This application requires to .net framework 4.6.1
and then when I'm trying to install .net framework 4.6.1, it throws an error which says:
- .Net Framework 4.6.1 is not competible with this PC.

OS: Windows Server 2008 R2

Comment: Check the project properties to make sure it's targeting the framework you think it's using

Comment: Do you maybe use a library or a Nuget Package wich is using 4.6.1?

Comment: I checked and rebuilt my all projects to ensure these are .net framework 4.5

Comment: How can I find the nuget packages in my solution?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see that **Windows Server 2008 R2 SP2** ("R2" and "SP2") does exist.

**Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1** supports .NET 4.6.1 (up to current 4.7.2)

**Windows Server 2008 SP2** does not support .NET versions higher than 4.6

see [Microsoft Docs: .NET Framework system requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/framework/get-started/system-requirements#supported-server-operating-systems)

Comment: I'm sorry that is Windows Server 2008 R2. I've edited it

Comment: Is SP1 installed?

Comment: I think SP1 is not installed :(

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to double check if in fact every library and especially the main application are set to 4.5. 
Did you publish the application with the publishing assistant? Maybe there is a wrong prerequisite enabled. [image]

Comment: I'have checked also this scrren and unchecked this option

Comment: Have you looked inside the app.config? It should show the same as the properties tab but you never know...

Comment: <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7" />
  </startup>

Comment: Nothing changed.

Comment: Ok. Have you tried a "Find in Files" with notepad++ or so? The only further file i found where the .NET Version is referenced is the csproj file. Maybe there is a broken reference? Ans also I would try to delete the object folder and rebuild.

Comment: I've found some lines in setup project .vdprof file which writes .net "framework 4.6.1". I've delete those lines. I've cleaned and built again the setup but nothing changed. Now I've removed setup project and I'm gonna recreate.